# Is there a way to do nested import in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import

I want to achieve something similar to what you can achieve in C++ with a header .h file so that all of my files don't have to keep importing the same thing that I need to use.

Something like....

**include.js**

```
import React from 'React';
import {Container, Row, Col} from 'react-bootstrap';
```

**first_file.js**

```
import './include.js';
```

**second_file.js**

```
import './include.js';
```

Rather than both first_file.js and second_file.js requiring to import the same things over and over again?

Comment: Only if you also export them. Every JS file is an island unto itself: imported entities are only available with the file that's importing them. The point of explicit imports is to prevent pollution, not enable it (and so you know precisely what's being imported into a module).

Comment: So is it bad practice what I am trying to achieve then?

Comment: That's more a matter of opinion than anything else. You can look at the docs on MDN for import/export to see what's possible, then make a decision whether or not it's a "good" or "bad" idea based on what's possible, whatever coding standards you have in place, etc.